# Progress Dialog On a Button click

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to show a Progress Dialog with a progress wheel on a button click.I have tried ,but it was not working properly..

```
 protected void onStart( ) 
  {
  _oSubmit.setOnClickListener( new android.view.View.OnClickListener( )
     {
      @Override
      public void onClick( android.view.View v ) 
        {
        _oProgressDialog = android.app.ProgressDialog.show(UserRegistration.this, 
                                              "Please wait", "Submitting...", true);
        _oProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
       }
        _oProgressDialog.dismiss( ) ;
    }) ;
```

Comment: What is happening? Why you dint added logs in onClick so it could be confirm that your code is executing?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your code from onStart(), and add it to onCreate(). If it is in onCreate(). please post complete code.

And first remove that dismiss() method from there, and check whether atleast the progressdialog works without putting dismiss, then put the dismiss at the point where the work of your progressdialog is over..maybe use a timer, or use a thread and close the dialog in a handler..

Answer (score 2):

First of all why you are adding this code in `onStart()`. Add it inside `onCreate()` method.Also i think you forgot to call:

```
_oProgressDialog.show();
```

And remove **_oProgressDialog.dismiss( ) ;** and put anywhere where you want to dismiss it or you can go for Timer which will cancel your progressdialog after somtime.

Comment: @Amith add it inside onCreate(). Remove dismiss from thr. Still if it doesn't work put the updated code here.